# autofill multiple textboxes based on single textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have three textboxes and when i am writing something in first textbox then i am sending the value to state.jsp and showing it like
   out.println(firsttextboxvalue); by 2nd textbox response ID. But i want to fill up 3rd text box as a different value in response in that onkeyup event in 1st textbox. How can i achieve it?

### auto.jsp

```
 $("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
  $.get('state.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {
     $("#textbox2").val(responseData);//getting value in 2nd text box
     $("#textbox3").val(responseData);// here also i am receiving same value as that 2nd textbox, how can i get a different value here?
  });
});
```

### state.jsp

```
<%
     String firsttextbox=request.getParameter("count");
      out.println(firsttextbox); //displayed in 2nd textbox plus it is also showing the  below 3rdtextbox value, but i want to display out.println(firsttextbox); by 2nd textbox id only
      String 3rdtextbox="3rd textbox value";
      out.println(3rdtextbox); // it also displayed 3rdtextbox value plus it is also showing the  2nd textbox value
      //How can i separate these two outputs so that `first println() will be displayed in 2nd textbox and 3rd println() will be displayed in 3rd text box?`
%>
```

Any help

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write another answer for you tonight, but you should look into returning the data from your jsp in JSON format since that gives you an easy way to encode multiple values into the same string such that you can easily extract them in your JavaScript.

Comment: ok nnnnnn i am trying it but if u will get time then please help me by providing an answer, i require it urgently

Comment: anyone who can provide me the answer please?

Comment: @nnnnnn can you please tell me about json format by an example?

Comment: @Valky thanks for response well i have got the solution for my question before, anyways i have upvoted your answer

Comment: Thanks, but ckeck it, like that no one else will loose his time to reply ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know jsp coding, but do something like that :

```
<%
     String firsttextbox=request.getParameter("count");
     String 3rdtextbox="3rd textbox value";
     out.println(firsttextbox+'|'+3rdtextbox);// + for concatenation ?
%>
```

And in your js :

```
    $("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
      $.get('state.jsp', {count : this.value}, function(responseData) {
        result=responseData.split('|');
            $("#textbox2").val(result[0]);
            $("#textbox3").val(result[1]);
      });
});
```